# Confusingly high loyalty statistics from Google Analytics (Android)

Tags: android, google-analytics

3,845 first time sessions, 3,543 second time sessions. That means 92% of our users come back a second time.

I feel like that kind of retention rate is very unusual for an Android app. I'm concerned that I'm interpreting these numbers incorrectly

[image: 92 % of our users return a second time?!]

Here's the code I'm using to record sessions:

```
public class Tracker {

public static final String TAG = "Tracker";

private static final String flurryId = "********************";

public static void startTrackers(Activity a) {
    Log.v(TAG, "start trackers");

    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(a);
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(a, flurryId);

    // set flurry properties
    String versionName = Global.getVersionName(a);
    FlurryAgent.setVersionName(versionName);
    FlurryAgent.setUserId(Global.userID(a));
}

public static void endTrackers(Activity a) {
    Log.v(TAG, "end trackers");

    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(a);
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(a);
}
```

These functions get called in `onStart()` in the main `Activity`:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Tracker.startTrackers(this);
    Tracker.trackPageView("/" + LaunchpadFragment.NAME);
}

public synchronized void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Tracker.endTrackers(this);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> 3,845 first time sessions, 3,545 second time sessions. That means 92% of our users come back a second time.

While this seems *very* familiar to a question posted early today but is now deleted... you aren't reading the data correctly. These numbers aren't cumulative. Under your logic: of the 659 users that have used the app 8 times, more than 2000+ of them came back to use it 9-14 times... That wouldn't make sense.

The data should be read that:

- 19% of your users use the app *only* once  (3800 / 20500)
- 17% use the app *only* twice               (3500 / 20500)
- etc